# Couldn't call cs method in client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call my .cs method in client side to set the Checked attribute of `asp:checkbox`. My checkbox control is as follows:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# ProcessEntityStatus(Eval("Deleted"))%>' Text="Active" Enabled="false" />
```

Code behind method:

```
public bool ProcessEntityStatus(bool value)
{
    if (!value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. Can any one help me please.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? You probably need to cast that eval to an explicit bool.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. It is tagged with jQuery, and mentions "client side", but only shows ASP.Net code and c# server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this and see if it helps.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%= ProcessEntityStatus(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Deleted")))%>' Text="Active" Enabled="false" />

public string ProcessEntityStatus(bool value)
    {

       if (!value)
       {
           return "true";
       }
       else
       {
           return "false";
       }
    }
```